# Laravel 5 の「Auth::user()」のプロパティにJOINしたデータを追加したい

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.0 で標準付属の Auth による User 認証を使っています。
その場合 Auth::user()->name などで現在ログイン中のユーザーのプロパティが得られますが、
今回 role というプロパティをもたせ、Auth::user()->role で取得できるようにしたいと考えています。

users テーブルには新しいカラム「role_id」を作り、用意した roles テーブルの id とひもづける予定です。
SQL文は次のようなものです。

```
SELECT users.*, roles.name AS role FROM `users` INNER JOIN `roles` ON users.role_id = roles.id
```

辿って行くと、「vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php」の retrieveById() で処理が行われているようなので次のように書き換えて動作することを確認しました。

```
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    return $this->createModel()->newQuery()
        ->select(['users.*', 'roles.name as role'])
        ->join('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->find($identifier);

    // return $this->createModel()->newQuery()->find($identifier);
}
```

一応はこれでも目的の動作をしてはいますが、本来は何らかの拡張クラスを作って extend するべきなのでしょうか？
もしそうであればどのフォルダにどのような形で追加したら良いのでしょうか。
フレームワークの使い方自体まだ不慣れで良く理解できていません。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vendor配下はcomposerライブラリのディレクトリになりますので、
直接ソースコードを編集するのはお勧めしません。
updateの度に書き換えられますし、
updateをしないとなりますとバグフィックスなども受けられません。

質問にあるような認証情報を取得できるようにするには、方法はいくつかありますが、
フレームワークを学ぶ上でも一番のベストプラクティスは認証ドライバーの追加、または拡張です。

その際にどのフォルダに置くか、ですがLaravel5以上であればデフォルトのオートローダがpsr-4に対応していますので、
ディレクトリやファイルの場所は特に関係ありません。
ここでは **app/Autheinticate** 配下に作成する例として紹介します。

`Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php`がデフォルトでEloquentを利用する認証クラスになっていますので、  
該当のretrieveByIdメソッドをオーバライドするために、
`app/Autheinticate/AuthUserProvider.php`としてファイルを作成します。

```
<?php
namespace App\Authenticate;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

class AuthUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
     * @param  mixed  $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        return $this->createModel()->newQuery()
            ->join('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
            ->find($identifier, ['users.*', 'roles.name as role']);
    }

}
```

次に認証ドライバーとして追加します。(ここではwith_roleという名前にします)  
ドライバー追加はサービスプロバイダーを利用しますので、
app/Providers配下にサービスプロバイダーを作成します。

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Authenticate\AuthUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['auth']->extend('with_role', function () {
            $model = $this->app['config']['auth.model'];
            return new AuthUserProvider($this->app['hash'], $model);
        });
    }
}
```

サービスプロバイダーからサービスコンテナへは`$this->app`でアクセスできます。
認証クラスはサービスコンテナにauthという名前で登録されていますので、
認証クラスへアクセスしてextendメソッドを利用します。  
このメソッドはドライバを追加する場合に利用します。
(認証、キャッシュ、セッション、データベース、ファイルストレージなどで利用するメソッドです)
認証に利用するEloquentを継承したクラスをconfig/auth.phpのmodelから取得して、
作成したAuthUserProviderクラスのコンストラクタに渡す引数を記述します。
(Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProviderを継承しているため)  
作成したApp\Providers\AuthServiceProviderクラスをconfig/app.phpのproviders配列へ追記し、
最後にconfig/auth.phpのdriverにwith_roleを記述します。

```php
'driver' => 'with_role',
```

あとはいつも通り`\Auth::user()`で取得できます。  
ドライバーを追加するメリットとしては、同じように追加したドライバや既存のドライバを

```
Auth::driver('eloquent')->user();
Auth::driver('with_role')->user();
```

などdriverメソッドを利用してそれぞれの用途に合わせた場面で認証情報を変更したり、
ログインなども分けることができます。

最新の5.1のマニュアルにはありませんでしたが、下記にも記載されていますので参考にしてみてください。
5.1でも拡張方法は同様です。
[Laravel 5.0 公式 | Extending The Framework](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending)
[Laravel 5.0 日本語訳 | フレームワークの拡張](http://readouble.com/laravel/5/0/dev/ja/extending.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法で目的の動作を実現できました。「config/app.php」の providers に拡張したクラスを登録するための独自の ServiceProvider を登録するのですね。とても参考になりました。

Comment: providersへの追加が抜けていました・・
この場合、Authを利用してユーザー情報にアクセスするたびにクエリが発行されますが、Cacheの操作を組み合わせることでDBへの通信コスト削減や高速化も期待できますので是非チャレンジしてみてください。

Answer (score 2):

laravelの標準ORMである、Eloquentで実装するのが一般的かと思います。
Roleモデルを作成し、belongsToMany()メソッドを使って、Userモデルと多対多のリレーションで紐付けます。テーブルは rolesテーブルと、role_userテーブルを作成します。
詳細な手順は下記の参考サイトをご覧ください。

参考サイト

- [初めてのLARAVEL 5 : (33) 多対多のリレーション モデル/DB編](https://laravel10.wordpress.com/2015/03/30/%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AElaravel-5-33-%E5%A4%9A%E5%AF%BE%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%ABdb%E7%B7%A8/)
- [Eloquent: Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: belongsTo() と belongsToMany() の両方を試してみました。
どちらも認証時のクエリ「select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '6' limit 1」と belongsToMany() の「select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` 〜」の２つのクエリが発生してしまいます。

Joinでまとめて一つのクエリにしようと思っていたのですが、そのようにするのはあまり一般的ではないのでしょうか。

Comment: N+1クエリー問題を軽減するには、Eager Loadingを使います。
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
一覧を表示するような場合には、N+1クエリー問題は深刻ですが、Auth::User()からroleを確認する為に、２つのクエリが発生するのは、それほど負荷にもならないので、問題無いように思います。

Comment: Eager Loading というのもあるのですね。1+1クエリーにまで抑えこみたいときにぜひ使ってみようと思います。

Comment: Elocuentで実装しておけば、roleの追加・変更・削除、userのroleの変更も簡単に出来るので、応用範囲は広がるかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

laravelアプリで、userに roleや Permissionを付与したいということであれば、[zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) パッケージを使うもの良いかと思います。

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: 情報有り難うございます。
今回はroleの他にも独自のプロパティを追加していこうと思いますので、練習も兼ねて手動で追加する方法を学んでおきたいと考えています。

Comment: roleとpermissionのリレーションや、hasRole()やcan()等のメソッド、仕様やソースを見るだけでも、かなり参考になります。